# Push on array of prefilled arrays sets all elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, fill

I'm struggling with a weird `Array.prototype.fill` behaviour:

```
const arr = new Array(5)
   .fill([]);
arr[0].push('element pushed to 0 only');
console.log(arr[1]); // ['element pushed to 0 only']
```

All of the items inside the array are filled with this string. I assume all of the `[]` array-s are pointing to the same array, but I don't see why, could anyone explain?

Answer (score 2):

In `fill([])`, the argument `[]` is evaluated before the call to `fill`.

It's the same as

```
const subarray = [];
const arr = new Array(5);
arr.fill(subarray);
```

which is the same as

```
const subarray = [];
const arr = new Array(5);
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) arr[i] = subarray;
```

In other words you have the same sub array at all indices: `arr[1]` is `arr[0]`.

If you want to have different subarrays, you coul do

```
const arr = Array.from({length:5}, ()=>[]);
```

Comment: but this is happening even if I use the new syntax:
```const arr = new Array(5)
   .fill(new Array());
arr[0].push('element pushed to 0 only');
console.log(arr[1]);```

Comment: What new syntax ? calling fill to put the same array everywhere?

Comment: I meant the `new Array()` syntax - I would assume this is creating new instances for sure

Comment: @AdamNagy new Array isn't the problem. The problem is you're filling with the same element everywhere.

Comment: GOTCHA! I see now, I was blind so far, thanks a lot! :)